# Generate swagger docus from java Annotations, missing security definitions

Tags: java, maven, annotations, swagger

I use the swagger maven plugin to generate the swagger documentation at build time.

This works fine for the basic `@SwaggerDefinition` annotations.
But the sub-part `securityDefinition` is not generated in the final json and yaml files.

I'm using [swagger-maven-plugin](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin) in version 3.1.4

Any ideas what might be missing?

```
@SwaggerDefinition(
        info = @Info(
                description = "Interact with example",
                version = "V1.1.0",
                title = "The example API",
                termsOfService = "http://example.com",
                contact = @Contact(
                   name = "André Schild", 
                   email = "a.schild@aarboard.ch", 
                   url = "http://example.com"
                ),
                license = @License(
                    name = "example License",
                    url = "http://example.com/"
                )
        ),
        host = "api.example.com",
        basePath = "/api/v1",
        consumes = {"application/json"},
        produces = {"application/json"},
        schemes = {SwaggerDefinition.Scheme.HTTPS},
        securityDefinition = @SecurityDefinition(
                basicAuthDefinions = {
                        @BasicAuthDefinition(key = "basicAuth")},
                apiKeyAuthDefintions = {
                        @ApiKeyAuthDefinition(key = "exampleAuth", name = "apiKey", in = ApiKeyLocation.HEADER)}),
          tags = {
                @Tag(name = "API", description = "Api for example"),
                @Tag(name = "V1", description = "V1 Api for example")
        }, 
        externalDocs = @ExternalDocs(
                value = "example",
                url = "http://example.com"
        )
)
```

Here what the final swagger file looks like:

```
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "Interact with example"
  version: "V1.1.0"
  title: "The example API"
  termsOfService: "http://example.com"
  contact:
    name: "André Schild"
    url: "http://example.com"
    email: "a.schild@aarboard.ch"
  license:
    name: "example License"
    url: "http://example.com/"
host: "api.example.com"
basePath: "/api/v1"
tags:
- name: "categories"
  description: "Operations about categories"
paths:
  /categories:
    get: 
.... and more paths/definitions....
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I got this working for me was by creating a separate class/interface and annotating it with `@SwaggerDefinition` with the security definitions. And it provided the security definition for all the APIs.

Like this:

```
@SwaggerDefinition(securityDefinition = @SecurityDefinition(apiKeyAuthDefinitions = { @ApiKeyAuthDefinition(key = "ApiKey", name = "Authorization", in = ApiKeyLocation.HEADER) }))
public interface SwaggerSecurityDefinition {

}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. this does not work for me. I have created the new interface class, in the same location as the other definitions, but it does not include it in the documentation...

Answer (score 0):

@Andre:

to get the solution of ritesh working you need to include the security definition in your resource classes:

```html
@Api(value = "/example", description = "", authorizations = {
        @Authorization(
                value = "ApiKey"
        )
})
public class ExapleResource {
...
}
```

or you could use the swagger bean to configure the definitions globally.
A good example is found in the [swagger-examples](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/blob/master/java/java-jersey-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/sample/Bootstrap.java)

Answer (score 0):

Configure swagger-maven-plugin if using it (https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin):

```
<securityDefinition>
    <name>MybasicAuth</name>
    <type>basic</type>
</securityDefinition>
```